# Transition in CSS3 not working in Firefox or Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, css-transitions

I am creating a small business page. I have a background image that I created for my navigation buttons. I want them to have the transition effect for when hovering over the image. It works in Chrome, but I can’t figure out why my code won’t work in Firefox or Internet Explorer.

```css
.nav li a.active {
    background-image: url('../images/02amainhover.png');
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: center center;
    width: 245px;
    height: 74px;
    left: 72px;
    top: 432px;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all .8s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease-out;
}
.nav li a.active:hover {
    background-image: url('../images/03amainhover.png');
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: center center;
    width: 245px;
    height: 74px;
    left: 72px;
    top: 432px;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all .8s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all .8s ease-in;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things.  First is that you have wayyyyy too much repeated code.  Websites assume the same code until you tell it to change it, so copying all those styles is pointless.  You would only need to update it with the thing you want to transition.  That being said, you can't transition background images.  Please reference this list for transitioning styles:  https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animation-of-property-types-

Comment: This makes a little more since, I guess that would explain why it's not working properly! Thank you, I can see that reference sheet being of very much good use to me. And as far as the repeated code part, I had thought that was good to add? Somebody before had once mentioned that sometimes browsers needed the repeated code for more specification and that the lack of a repeated code can sometimes be the problem of why a code isn't properly functioning?

Comment: older browsers (IE6) needed repeated code for `:hover` for any changed values. Basically it needed to know both how to change on `:hover` and how to change back again.

Comment: If people are still coding for IE6, they're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can make two images with position: absolute and different z-indexes. The image on the top could have opacity transition from 1 to 0. It will work in all browsers.

Comment: And turning down the opacity can give me the transitioning look that I'm after? Because I don't want any fancy transitioning, just a simple "all" transition effect so my images transition from one to the other when hovered on?

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris Stanley pointed out you cannot transition background images.

You have many options depending on the exactly what your transition is meant to look like. I haven't seen the images.

- You can use [filters](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/)
- You can combine multiple images in a single image file (grid, top/bottom, etc) and then use background positioning to "move" (instantly) from one to the other. You can combine this with other transitions or filters to provide additional effects. This is a pretty old trick that you can put a new twist on with added transitions and filters.

EDIT (after seeing images):
your new code might look like this:

```
.nav li a.active {
    background-image: url('../images/02amainhover.png');
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: center center;
    width: 245px;
    height: 74px;
    left: 72px;
    top: 432px;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all 0.8s ease-out;

    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

}

.nav li a.active:hover {

    filter: invert(100%);
    transition: all 0.8s ease-in;
}
```

(I don't think you need the `-moz-transition` anymore either.)

Comment: So what you mean, is that I can add the transitioning code or a code similar to the filters and the effect would be the same?

Comment: probably not "the same", but you can still do a lot. I haven't seen your two images... it's possible you can create nearly the exact same effect, but I can't tell without having seen what you are trying to do.

Comment: I can show you my two images, I have the links for them: this is my main image: http://www.freewebs.com/aph-imvu/02amainhover.png and this is my second image: http://www.freewebs.com/aph-imvu/03amainhover.png

Comment: Basically, what I am trying to do is to transition the second image with the first image so that way, when it is hovered over, the image transitions to the lighter image that I have created.

Comment: It has the exact effect that I am going for in Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer and Firefox. So if I can get it to where it's similar to the effect it has in Chrome, but works in all browsers, that would be great and make this a lot less of a headache.

Comment: after seeing the images, you might be able to use a `filter: invert(100%)` as your transition and come out with the same effect. You will have to remove the shadow from the image and use a `box-shadow` instead otherwise the shadow will get inverted as well.